# Excel locking cells with a date and time not working

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I want to have a sheet were after I enter a truck number it automatically places the date and time in a following cell, that works no problem, but when I try to place a protection on the cells after data has been enter so it cannot be modify it gives me errors, what am I doing wrong?

I have selected the complete sheet and unlock the cells, then I have wrote this code on the visual basic for excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"
Target.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="YourPassword"


Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
For x = 2 To 1000
For y = 2 To 1000

If Cells(x, 3).Value <> "" And Cells(x, 5).Value = "" Then
Cells(x, 5).Value = Date & " " & Time
Cells(x, 5).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End If
Next
Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

If Cells(y, 6).Value <> "" And Cells(y, 7).Value = "" Then
Cells(y, 7).Value = Date & " " & Time
Cells(y, 7).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End If
Next
Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

[[image: ![after dooing all the coding inside one Worksheet_SelectionChange] ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ovH.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ovH.jpg)
[this is the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAZN9.jpg)
[image: this is the sheet]

after I apply the code for the protection the time and date doesnt stamp anymore

Comment: You cannot have more than one `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event. You have to combine them.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time trying something like this, can explain me how?

Comment: because when I have tried it it gives me another error

Comment: Show what you have tried when you combined them in your question. You can edit your question and add those details.

Comment: added new pictures and code

Comment: Your update shows the `Worksheet_Change`, not the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event that was duplicated.

Comment: Put `ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="YourPassword"` at the end of the sub

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have tried everything and can't get it to work. do you have a sample I can look at?

Comment: Could you tell us in which case should the timestamp be added to column `E` and in which case to column `G`, e.g. when `scan out` in column `C` is entered for column `E` but only if there is a truck in column `D`, and when `scan in` in column `F` is entered for column `G` anyway?

Comment: the idea is that when I scan a badge (A) it will auto populate the person name (B), when I scan out(C) it will populate (D) and place a date and time stamp on (E), when I scan in (F) it will stamp date and time on (G).

Comment: I want to have a log on when a driver comes in I scan their badge it will populate their name then I will hand them out a truck key, will scan the key and record what truck they took and at what time, at the end of the day when he comes back we scan the key again and it will record the date and time that happened, but I want to protect the data so it doesn't get erase by mistake.

Comment: the population of data I have been able to do, but at the time I try to protect the cells I have not been able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

### Worksheet Change: Monitoring 2 Non-Adjacent Columns

- Adjust the values in the constants section, especially the password ('pw').

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ScanTrucks Target
End Sub

Private Sub ScanTrucks(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Scan In
    Const siCol As String = "C"
    Const diCol As String = "E"
    ' Scan Out
    Const soCol As String = "F"
    Const doCol As String = "G"
    ' Both
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const afCol As String = "B"
    Const pw As String = "123"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    ' Scan In
    Set scrg = ws.Columns(siCol)
    With scrg
        Set srg = Intersect(Target, _
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1))
    End With
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        For Each sCell In srg.Cells
            If Len(CStr(sCell.Value)) > 0 Then
                Set dCell = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(diCol)
                If Len(CStr(dCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                    Set drg = RefCombinedRange(drg, dCell)
                End If
            End If
        Next sCell
    End If
    
    ' Scan Out
    Set srg = Nothing
    With scrg.EntireRow.Columns(soCol)
        Set srg = Intersect(Target, _
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1))
    End With
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        For Each sCell In srg.Cells
            If Len(CStr(sCell.Value)) > 0 Then
                Set dCell = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(doCol)
                If Len(CStr(dCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                    Set drg = RefCombinedRange(drg, dCell)
                End If
            End If
        Next sCell
    End If
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Unprotect, format, write and protect.
    
    ws.Unprotect Password:=pw
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ws.Columns(afCol).AutoFit
    
    With drg
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Value = Now
        .Locked = True
    End With
 
SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not ws.ProtectionMode Then ws.Protect Password:=pw
      
    Exit Sub
    
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a range combined from two ranges.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: this code looks good, I haven't been coding for a while so I'm rusted and might sound stupid, but this happened, first time I scanned for column A it placed name on B great, went I scanned C it populated D and E, but from there nothing work anymore, I cannot input anything else. it doesn't even give me an error that I can show you. any Ideas?

Comment: The scan in is the one that kicks me out

Comment: It's working fine on my end. As you put values in columns `C` and `F`, columns `E` and `G` respectively get time-stamped and locked (if they're empty). There was a mistake, in scan out it should be `Set srg = Intersect(srg.EntireRow.Columns(soCol), Target)` (so the header `F1` (`G1`) is excluded). It's already corrected in the post. BTW, the error-handler is showing errors in the Immediate window (in VBE `Ctrl+G`). Maybe you missed them.

Comment: I made a few changes. Maybe try it now and look in the Immediate window if it doesn't work. To find out which line is throwing the error (if it shows), uncomment the line `On Error GoTo ClearError`.

Comment: After I do the first input either on column C or F it blocks and I can't add anything else, all I hear is a ding and a error message flashes and goes away very quick, I cant read it.

Comment: I tested the code in separate spreadsheet and it works, but in my workbook it doesn't, I don't know why